# How do I start studying Gabor Filters ?

Tags: image-processing, filters, gabor

I know very basic image processing. Please suggest me how do I and where do I start learning Gabor Filters ?

Comment: I would suggest starting with [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gabor_filter).

Comment: http://mplab.ucsd.edu/tutorials/gabor.pdf

Answer (score 3):

You know what I actually found really useful, Gabor's original paper, "Theory of Communication":

http://redwood.berkeley.edu/w/images/b/b6/Gabor.pdf

Of particular interest is how Gabor used banks of reeds, tuned to different frequencies, to visualise his filters. For me this led to a good conceptual understanding, especially of the uncertainty principle, before diving into the mathematics.